# Summing instance variable of objects [inside an array of objects] that have same one specific instance variable

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

If I have three arrays of object named car, and say the class has the following instance variables:

1. String carName;
2. int numberOfDoors;

This is how my main would look like with the arrays :

```
 car[] volkswagen2016Array = new car[10];
 car[] volkswagen2017Array = new car[10];
 car[] volkswagen2018Array = new car[10];
```

How do I form a for loop, or a foreach loop to iterate through all these arrays and sum the numberOfDoors variable if the carName is same in all these arrays?
Thanks.

Edit: What I have tried :

```
for (car a : volkswagen2016Array) {
    if (a == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        String carName = a.getCarName(); // a gettter function inside the class
        if (a.getCarName().equalsIgnoreCase(carName)) {
            doorSum += a.getDoorNum(); //doorSum is an int variable inside main, int doorSum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex yes edited the question,while far from what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Your code looks to be close to what you want, except you're testing the same car name for equality. You need to get the desired car name String *before* the loop, and then test if for equality with the array items within the loop

Comment: If you want to take care about car name you need to provide a name which will be used to compare with `a.getName()`. For example you want to sum all doors for `Jetta`: `final String carName = "Jetta";` and check this name in foreach loop.

Comment: @MichałZiober thank you for the help, but what I want to do is get the name each time I enter the loop and then look whether there is another car with the same name in another foreach loop for the other two arrays. Is it possible?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, there's the thing that the name of the car will not be available in thr main class, I'll try to iterate throughout the arrays and get as many different car names as there are, and then check the other arrays whether there are cars with the names I have taken, say in the first foreach loop of the first array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to iterate 3 arrays and if 3 `Car` arrays are of same size `for loop` is better than `for each`

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<volkswagen2016Array.length; i++)  {

      if(volkswagen2016Array[i].getCarName().equals(carName)) {
             sum += volkswagen2016Array[i].getNumberOfDoors();
             }

       if(volkswagen2017Array[i].getCarName().equals(carName)) {
             sum += volkswagen2017Array[i].getNumberOfDoors();
             }

       if(volkswagen2018Array[i].getCarName().equals(carName)) {
             sum += volkswagen2018Array[i].getNumberOfDoors();
             }

   }
```

By using java-8 streams

```
int sum = IntStream.range(0, volkswagen2016Array.length)
          .map(i->Stream.of(volkswagen2016Array[i],volkswagen2017Array[i],volkswagen2018Array[i])
                  .filter(c->c.getName().equals(carName)).mapToInt(Car::getNumberOfDoors).sum()).sum();
```

Comment: Hmm, I think with this one, I still have to provide carName. I was thinking of getting the names from the first array, and if there is another car of the same name in the other arrays then I'd add the numbers of the cars in total to the sum. I'll try this one once I reach my pc, thank you so much!

Comment: yeah I tried it but it did not work, I used another workaround which is a bit of a hacky solution, should I post it?